# install.php displayed instead of update.php

Tags: updating

This looks similar to

[Drupal 7 keeps returning to install.php and reports no settings.php but it's all there](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/218881/drupal-7-keeps-returning-to-install-php-and-reports-no-settings-php-but-its-all?newreg=4d728c3667dd487fa42c13a6f2d90897)

but I only just registered so can't comment.

This is a single site (still drupal 7.59). free_access is true, sites/defaults/settings.php is writeable by all (website on local machine to try to figure out solution.) Connection to mysql seems OK.

One clue: if I proceed to install, "Verify requirements" says things like:

> The Drupal installer requires that the ./sites/default/default.settings.php file not be modified in any way from the original download.

yet from within the nginx root directory:

```
# ls -l sites/default/default.settings.php
-rw-r--r--  1 root  users  26250 May  3 15:53 sites/default/default.settings.php
```

so where does drupal look? (I didn't find a mention of the root directory in the database...)

Comment: I should probably have also stated the obvious: install.php is in the nginx root directory.

Comment: Did you changed the default.settings.php or is it at least in the directory ?

Comment: In my original question I show that default.settings.php is in the directory, and $ diff sites/default/default.settings.php /tmp/drupal-7.59/sites/default/default.settings.php shows no difference.

Comment: <?php
    define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
    require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
    drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_CONFIGURATION);
    print_r(conf_path());
    ?>
outputs: "sites/default"

Comment: Do you have drush installed ? If so can you paste what "drush status" says ?

Comment: I haven't - I had a quick look at the drush on github yesterday, and it looked as though it was for drupal 8 only. I am slowly getting a clue: drupal looks for the settings.php file in the right place. If I require_once the settings.php file, I get an error. The oddity at the moment is that I tried "if (include(DRUPAL_ROOT . '/nonexistent.php') == FALSE)" and include did not return FALSE. (The file does not exist.) I also tried to include a file which just sets a variable, and echo variable doesn't output anything => into debugging this installation.

Comment: Ignore previous comment: I should have written "if ((include DRUPAL...

Answer (score 0):

The script useful for tracking this down was:

```
<?php
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_CONFIGURATION);
print_r(getcwd()); echo '<br>';
print_r(conf_path()); echo '<br>';
$settings_path = DRUPAL_ROOT . '/' . conf_path() . '/settings.php';
echo "settings_path: $settings_path<br>";
$ret = realpath($settings_path);
echo "ret: $ret<br>";
?>
```

The clue was that $ret was empty. From the realpath documentation:

> Note:
>   The running script must have executable permissions on all directories in the hierarchy, otherwise realpath() will return FALSE.

Changing

```
drwxr-x---  3 root  users  512 May 16 14:34 default
```

to have world executable permission worked around the problem.